# Column Mapping in Same Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Students  Score1  Students  Score2  Students  Score3
   A        50       B        88       A        48
   B        40       A        76       C        47
   C        28       C        74       B        40
```

How do I turn the above dataframe into the format below:

```
Students  Score1  Score2  Score3
   A        50      76      48
   B        40      88      40
   C        28      74      47
```

The only approach I'm aware is by applying iloc onto them into separate dataframe and then join them together or is there a one way method to do so?
*Python read the duplicated columns as Students, Students.1, Students.2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

With `concat` and `groupby`

```
pd.concat([
    d.set_index('Students')
    for _, d in df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1]) // 2, axis=1)
], axis=1)

   Score1  Score2  Score3
A      50      76      48
B      40      88      40
C      28      74      47
```

---

```
pd.concat([
    d.set_index('Students')
    for _, d in df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1]) // 2, axis=1)
], axis=1).rename_axis('Students').reset_index()

  Students  Score1  Score2  Score3
0        A      50      76      48
1        B      40      88      40
2        C      28      74      47
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.concat` with `pd.DataFrame.iloc` to iterate your columns pairwise:

```
res = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, 2*i:2*i+2].set_index('Students') for i in \
                 range(int(len(df.columns) / 3 + 1))], axis=1)

print(res)

   Score1  Score2  Score3
A      50      76      48
B      40      88      40
C      28      74      47
```

You can elevate index to column à la @piRSquared's solution:

```
print(res.rename_axis('Students').reset_index('Students'))

  Students  Score1  Score2  Score3
0        A      50      76      48
1        B      40      88      40
2        C      28      74      47
```